# "[open]" + "[source]" versus "[open-source]"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

I find the tags [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [source](/questions/tagged/source) confusing when used together to denote [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source), yet there seem to be many questions tagged this way. See many of the posts in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open+source

Am I missing some hidden meaning?

Also, [open](/questions/tagged/open) makes sense by itself, e.g., when working with files. But does [source](/questions/tagged/source) make sense by itself? Note that there is already [source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code).

Comment: How about blacklisting using [tag:open] and [tag:source] together?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those users are doing it wrong: tags need to have meaning on their own. There should be no compound tags on any SE site.

Most of those questions also shouldn't be tagged [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source), as it's not relevant to the question that the software described happens to be open source.

I'd suggest that both the [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [source](/questions/tagged/source) tags should be nuked from orbit. They don't seem to be of any use.

Comment: Thanks. Then if nobody minds I'll go through them and submit a retag request, at least syntactically if not semantically.

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu This has to be done manually. Fabian: there are legitimate uses of [tag:open] and [tag:source]; it's only the posts tagged with both that should be retagged.

Comment: @Gilles: Agreed. I'm doing it manually.

Comment: @Gilles I can't really imagine any valid uses of those tags, from a quick glance at the questions tagged with those tags I don't see any reason to keep those tags. If they should be kept, they should at least be renamed to something less ambiguous (e.g. open-file for questions about that)

Answer (score 7):

This is probably due to newbies just typing away at tags and not knowing the dash-ing convention.

[open](/questions/tagged/open) looks like it needs to be synonymerized. [source](/questions/tagged/source)... well, I dunno.. Someone should first comb through the tag(both tags actually) and check for legitimate uses. Then synonym+merge. Or blacklist. Since they'll just keep coming back.

EDIT:

Looks like "open" means "open-file" at times, and "source" can mean source code. Proposed battle plan:

- Go through [open](/questions/tagged/open), and retag all questions to [open-file](/questions/tagged/open-file) or [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) accordingly
- Go through [source](/questions/tagged/source), and retag all questions to [source-code](/questions/tagged/source-code) or [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) accordingly
- **Blacklist** [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [source](/questions/tagged/source)
- Eat waffles

Comment: [tag:open] is mostly used for opening files. I don't see what it could be synonymized to. [tag:source] is less clear.

Comment: @Gilles: in which case, its best left alone. Blacklist source if it doesnt have  any other uses.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me wish SO had an extensive API like Wikipedia--and bot support(ability to make automated edits from an approved bot account nearly silently). On Wikipedia I'd have taught my bot to do such a `open AND source` job in a jiffy :/

Comment: @Gilles Looking at [tag:open], there's too many cases where *open* has nothing to do with files. But regardless of that, I prefer the tag to be explicit about what's getting opened (e.g. [tag:file-open] or [tag:open-file]).

Answer (score 2):

The tags have now been destroyed and replaced with [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source). In fact, both of those tags should probably be blacklisted. If you see either, make the tags more meaningful.

Comment: You mean that you did the retag manually on all questions with the [tag:open] and [tag:source] tags?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Yup, with the help of... some other user, I'll find his name eventually. As far as I know there's no automatic way to do it, is there?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that there should be no "compound tags" in any circumstances. While I agree that the specific example [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [source](/questions/tagged/source) shouldn't be allowed, it's only because neither the individual tags nor the combination are acceptable for Stack Overflow. Where one or both of the tags can stand alone, however, a compound tag may be appropriate. Here are some examples:

- [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) + [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) -> [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)
- [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon) + [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) -> [amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)
- [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter) + [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) -> [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)
- [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) + [video](/questions/tagged/video) -> [html5-video](/questions/tagged/html5-video)
- [android](/questions/tagged/android) + [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) -> [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity)

Note that especially in the second example, two tags can combine to form a new concept. In the case of [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity), the compound tag is useful to clarify the topic, since the tag [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) can hardly stand alone.