# Is it allowed to combine a specific tag (like asp.net-web-api) together with their low-level supertags (like asp.net and web-api)?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Last days I've noticed a few posts of users on Asp.Net Web Api that has a specific tag [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) but that were tagged by the users by (what I call) 'low-level supertags'

Examples:

- [SO post 15782088](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15782088/569101) using [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)[web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api)
- [SO post 15803688](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15803688/569101) using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api)
- [SO post 15801776](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15801776/569101) using [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)[web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api)

My first instinct would be to replace the low-level [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api)  tag with the more specific [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api).

But on second thought I believe some people might be looking/following at the more low-level tags so I think that just adding the specific tag is viable too..

*What's the general rule on this?*

Answer (score 4):

You're right when you would replace [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) with [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) since it seems that web-api is a very basic tag. It doesn't add any great value to the question because I find it too *wide*, too *generic*.

When looking at related tags of [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api):

- [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) × 201
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) × 133
- [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) × 110
- [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) × 98
- [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) × 86

It seems that most people use it in addition to asp.net* tag.

I think we could retag all questions (for example):

- [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) + [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) => [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) only
- [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) + [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) => [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) + [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4)
- [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) + [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) => [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) + [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)
- [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) + [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) => [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) + [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)

**Edit:**

Job done.

I don't know what should be done with:

- [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) + [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)  [x 49](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api+c#)
- [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) + [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)  [x 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api+.net)

Comment: +1 - good taxonomy. The proposed retagging makes sense to me (as an ASP.Net/MVC/Web API enthusiast).

Answer (score 2):

I once discussed this in [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127672/open-source-versus-open-source). I repeat it here:

> I disagree that there should be no "compound tags" in any
>   circumstances. While I agree that the specific example [open](/questions/tagged/open) and
>   [source](/questions/tagged/source) shouldn't be allowed, it's only because neither the
>   individual tags nor the combination are acceptable for Stack Overflow.
>   Where one or both of the tags can stand alone, however, a compound tag
>   may be appropriate. Here are some examples:
>
> - [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) + [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) -> [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)
> - [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon) + [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) -> [amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)
> - [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter) + [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) -> [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)
> - [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) + [video](/questions/tagged/video) -> [html5-video](/questions/tagged/html5-video)
> - [android](/questions/tagged/android) + [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) -> [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity)
>
> Note that especially in the second example, two tags can combine to
>   form a new concept. In the case of [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity), the
>   compound tag is useful to clarify the topic, since the tag [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) 
>   can hardly stand alone.

In this case, just like "android-activity", I think it's appropriate to combine the
two tags into "asp.net-web-api", since "web-api", unlike "asp.net", can hardly
stand alone.