# Remove [source] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So it appears it has [already been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127672/open-source-versus-open-source), but I came across the [source](/questions/tagged/source) tag this morning and it seemed pretty useless after looking at the just-over 1000 questions still tagged with it.

It's also being incorrectly used with tags like [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [control](/questions/tagged/control).

Should it be removed once and for all?

Comment: If the cleanup suggested in that question has been completed (which, apparently, it has not), a [source] -> [source-code] synonym would make sense (although honestly [source-code] seems fairly worthless to begin with; nearly every question on SO could include it)

Comment: @Wooble Exactly.

Comment: This is marked as duplicate yet nothing was ever done about it. I even linked to that exact post. What happens now?